# Is there a remote switch I can use to replace a switch located in a wall being removed?

Tags: electrical, walls, switch

I am removing two walls that contain light switches for the dining, and kitchen ceiling lights. Is there a wireless switch I can use for control, without fishing wires into the existing walls?

Answer (score 1):

That's possible, but I doubt that something like this would be up to any electrical code unless those are 3 way switches that have their counterparts somewhere else as they make wireless 3 way switches

Anyway, something like this seems like a bad idea. If you are remodeling anyway , then either fish the wires or open up the walls and patch them later. Nothing beats hardwired connection.

Comment: There are a lot of makers of wireless, battery operated switches like Leviton, Lutron, X10, Z-Wave and on... @Vitaliy is right.  All the wireless switches transmit a signal and then there has to be a receiver to receive the signal.  Unless you have a switch elsewhere, then the wireless switch will not work.  Also do you self a favor and don't try to add the receiver in the attic.  You're asking for trouble if you do.  Heat and electronics don't mix.